# Guessing random radio buttons

Tags: c#, random, radio-button

So far I've got the random number and radio buttons working, my specific questions is how to show the actual answer if the user guess wrong. I would show this on labelOutput in the if/else statement. Also I would like to give a hint as to the actual number before the person guess buy saying even or odd at labelHint. You can see which sections I'm working on via the comments in the code.

```
namespace GuessANumber
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        labelHint.Text = "Hover over for a hint";

        labelOutput.Visible = true;

        Init();

    }

    Random random = new Random();

    int correctAnswer;

    private void Init()
    {
        correctAnswer = random.Next(1, 6);
    }

    private bool UserSelectedRandomButton()
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            return (correctAnswer == 1);
        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            return (correctAnswer == 2);
        if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            return (correctAnswer == 3);
        if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
            return (correctAnswer == 4);
        if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
            return (correctAnswer == 5);
        return false;
    }


    private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        radioButton1.Enabled = false;
        radioButton2.Enabled = false;
        radioButton3.Enabled = false;
        radioButton4.Enabled = false;
        radioButton5.Enabled = false;

        labelOutput.Visible = true;

        if (UserSelectedRandomButton() == true)
        {
            labelOutput.Text = "You are correct!";
        }
        else
        {

            labelOutput.Text = (" Sorry, the correct answer is" + " " + correctAnswer);//now working :)
        }
        correctAnswer = random.Next(1, 6);
    }



    private void labelHint_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //still working on this, if the number is odd, label changes to odd statement, if even says even statement

        labelHint.Text = "The number is odd";


    }

    private void labelHint_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        labelHint.Text = "Hover over for a hint";
    }




    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Enabled = true;
        radioButton2.Enabled = true;
        radioButton3.Enabled = true;
        radioButton4.Enabled = true;
        radioButton5.Enabled = true;

        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
        radioButton5.Checked = false;

        labelOutput.Visible = false;




    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the hints not working and it not showing the "correct" answer have the same root problem. You are grabbing a new random number in the `UserSelectedRandomButton()` function, and then effectively throwing it away (because it goes out of scope).

To get the "correct answer" feature working, you need to assign that number to a class level variable, then reference it instead of calling `UserSelectedRandomButton` again, like this:

```
//This is our class level variable
int correctAnswer;
private bool UserSelectedRandomButton()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    correctAnswer = random.Next(1, 6);

    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 1);
    if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 2);
    if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 3);
    if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 4);
    if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 5);
    return false;

}


private void buttonsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Enabled = false;
    radioButton2.Enabled = false;
    radioButton3.Enabled = false;
    radioButton4.Enabled = false;
    radioButton5.Enabled = false;



    if (UserSelectedRandomButton() == true)
    {
        labelOutput.Text = "You are correct!";
    }
    else
    {

        labelOutput.Text = (" Sorry, the correct answer is" + " " + correctAnswer);//now working :)
    }
}
```

Now to get the hints working, you have to do the same thing (assign to a class level variable), but there is a problem. The random number is drawn when the user presses the "submit" button, so we have no idea what the number is when we display the hint! Probably the easiest way to solve that is to draw a number when the program starts (I'll put it in an "Init" function that you can call from somewhere) and then update it after we are done checking in "Submit" (it could also be done in "Reset").

```
Random random = new Random();

//This is our class level variable
int correctAnswer;

private void Init()
{
    correctAnswer = random.Next(1, 6);
}

private bool UserSelectedRandomButton()
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 1);
    if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 2);
    if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 3);
    if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 4);
    if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
        return (correctAnswer == 5);
    return false;

}


private void buttonsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Enabled = false;
    radioButton2.Enabled = false;
    radioButton3.Enabled = false;
    radioButton4.Enabled = false;
    radioButton5.Enabled = false;



    if (UserSelectedRandomButton() == true)
    {
        labelOutput.Text = "You are correct!";
    }
    else
    {

        labelOutput.Text = (" Sorry, the correct answer is" + " " + correctAnswer);//now working :)
    }
    correctAnswer = random.Next(1, 6);
}
```

Your tooltips would check against the "correctAnswer" variable before deciding to say "even" or "odd". You should also notice that I moved the `Random` class instance into the class scope (instead of having it at function scope). This is considered best practice for the Random class, as recreating it every time you use it reduces the "randomness" of the generated numbers. It also facilitates code-reuse, since we are now drawing a number in two places.

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: LordTakkera, I changed the initial post to reflect your code. On my end once I run the program I get the output of "Sorry, the correct answer is 0. Everytime I run the code, the number is 0

Comment: You never call init, so the first number is never generated. Try calling init in your constructor. It should be generating for the second button click though. Let me know if that fixes it!

Comment: You are correct, I'm an idiot. I fixed this issue and edited the original post and it is now working. I have to still work on the Hint label though it should work in the same way correct? EDIT: I got the hint section working, though in a different, more convoluted way than your explanation. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yep, you should be able to do something like `if (correctAnswer %2 == 0) label.Text = "even"; else label.Text = "odd";` I can include that in my answer if you would like.

Comment: Just wanted to add, I tried it your way and it also worked, thank you again.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!